# I am developing a game at unity and encountered a problem while using accelerometer

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer

I have written this code for adding a force on a 3d box using accelerometer but this has no effect on the box when running. Is there any way of using `AddForce` instead of `transform`?

[image]

Also I only want to add a force in the x-axis, means horizontally, and in no other direction. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please add the code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your rigidbody mass with AddForce(). Force by default works with Newton's Law, that force = mass x acceleration. You might want to play with the ForceMode optional parameter that can be passed like: `rb.AddForce(tilt, ForceMode.Acceleration)`. Acceleration adds a continuous acceleration to the rigidbody, ignoring its mass. More information on: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html

Or you might want to check `rb.MoveToPosition(Vector3)` that calculates force for you to move to specified position.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

Information on the default way AddForce works, Rigidbody2D works in a similar way minus the third dimension.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

And to restrict force to only the x axis you might want to look on constrains on your box, limiting by axis or rotation.